# Cosmos db - Copy from existing data for staging env

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have created `Cosmos db` with `Mongo db api`. Its working fine for my dev env. But now i want to copy it from dev to stage and prod env.

So i didn't find any option there on azure portal.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Using Azure Resource Manager templates, you can easily automate the deployment and configuration of your Azure resources. This tutorial shows how to deploy a web application and automatically configure Azure Cosmos DB account connection information.

You can find a step by step guide using the deployment template on [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-website)
Let me know if this helps.

Comment: will it create a new database or new cosmos azure account and db?

Comment: It does for the account. When you are referring to deploying to prod, do you mean from the emulator to publishing the DB or what specific steps ?

Comment: no. I mean i have already created a cosmos db account on azure with setting up mongo db database. It was meant for Dev env. Now i want to create another environment for Staging and Production. So for app service there is an option called "deployment slot" which i have created so i get staging app service. but for this "Staging service" i want to have a separate database so that i can use for staging environment. Hope i made myself clear.

Comment: got it, unfortunately it's not available for Mongo /Cosmos DB, I agree the deployment slots are super useful for web apps making the publishing from staging to prod through the swap easy. One suggestion i could make is using the emulator perhaps as a staging env, locally, then publishing in prod afterwards. I'd recommend putting your suggestion here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback

Comment: okay Thanks for your quick reply. Can you provide some insights on "emulator locally". I also wanted to know if i make emulator locally then it will be available to me only or other in my testing team can also use that?

Comment: it can run on the network, and would accept authentications as well, here's a full guide here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator

Answer (score 0):

- Software dependencies

  Download Python from https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/
- Download the script folder and run the following command

  1. py -m pip install azure.cosmos
  2. py .\deploy_db.py "Endpoint of Cosmosdb" "Primary Key" "DatabaseName"
- Create seed data python script file as **seed_data.py**

```py
import json
import os

def get_employees():
    employees = []
    for file in os.listdir("Data\Employees"):
        if file.endswith(".json"):
            employeesFile = os.path.join("Data\Employees", file)
            with open(employeesFile, encoding="utf8") as f:
                employees.append(json.load(f))
    return employees

def get_employee_details():
    employee_details = {}; 
    with open('SeedData/EmployeesDetails.json', encoding="utf8") as f:
       employee_details = json.load(f)
    return employee_details
```

- Create python script file names as **deploy_db.py**

```py
from azure.cosmos import exceptions, CosmosClient, PartitionKey
import seed_data
import sys

# Initialize the Cosmos client
endpoint = sys.argv[1]
key = sys.argv[2]
database = sys.argv[3]

# Create cosmosClient
client = CosmosClient(endpoint, key)

# Create a database
database_name = database
database = client.create_database_if_not_exists(id=database_name)

# Create Employees Container
container_name = 'Employees'
container = database.create_container_if_not_exists(
    id=container_name, 
    partition_key=PartitionKey(path="/id")
)

# Add see data to the Employees 
employee_details_to_create = seed_data.get_employee_details()
container.upsert_item(body=employee_details_to_create)
```

- Add this script in your DevOps pipeline and add to the pipline as
  automation, that runs on each build